# Windows 10 Movies & TV app overrides screen contrast settings in fullscreen

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, colors

I have just got myself a new Nvidia GPU and faced a problem with Windows Movies & TV app.

Whenever the app is in fullscreen mode and I either close its window or go to windowed mode, my display's contrast is lowered dramatically and stays that way even with the app closed and killed.
Interestingly, I can return to normal contrast just by opening Settings -> System -> Display -> Windows HD Color settings in fullscreen. Again, I do not have to change any settings, I just need to open the screen. It doesn't work if the Settings app is windowed. WTF, windows?

For the GPU I installed the latest Game Ready Driver ver. 511.79 (02.14.2022).
Every color-related setting in NVIDIA Control Panel is set to "Use NVIDIA setting".

I do not have any display profiles in Windows Color Management, and the "Use Windows display calibration" checkbox is unchecked.

I believe Windows is performing shenanigans with my color settings, but I am unable to locate where exactly I can disable it.

Where can the problem lie and how can I fix it?

Comment: A bit of a guess - becuse you have told windows to not interfere & handed everything off the the NVidia CP, you've stopped Windows being able to revert whatever profile was in use for the movie [possibly Rec709 for a movie player, though your 'lower contrast' symptom would belie that somewhat] because it has no default to revert to. Rec709 is similar to sRGB, but has a different gamma curve, so will look very odd when not being used for movie playback. It will nominally look 'darker' than sRGB, hence my earlier doubt. I'd try handing control back to Win & see what happens.

Comment: I initially handed everything to Nvidia as an attempt to combat this issue, cuz it first appeared with default settings (win-handled). 

After posting this I just started playing with every single setting and found out that I can directly specify the content type reported to the display (Desktop programs or Full-screen videos), effectively locking it to a single profile. Though it solves the issue, I feel like it's not the right way.

Comment: The screen ought to be initially calibrated to at least sRGB [most screens have that as their basic default to aim for]. This ought to then be controlled by your OS, via an .icc profile. For most consumer uses, this is sufficient. The video app may then try to compensate a known sRGB profile towards Rec709 [or it may not, depending on how smart it is]. One thing that always confuses both users & Windows is when 'HDR' comes into play. For everything except perhaps gaming, where it can giver a perceived improvement in skinning, it really ought to be left off. It's a terrible bit of guesswork.